# How to create win32 smartpone dll and call by C# DllImport in WinCE

Tags: c#, c++, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I need to implement a Win32 DLL and need call it by C# DllImport in WinCE.
So I create a Win32 Smart Device Project and choice Windows Mobile 5.0 Smartphone SDK,
and create a dll project with Export symbols option.
Then I add extern "C" key word before function declare:

.h

```
#ifdef WINCE2_EXPORTS
#define WINCE2_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WINCE2_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" WINCE2_API int __cdecl Add(int A,int B);
```

.cpp

```
extern "C" WINCE2_API int __cdecl Add(int A,int B)
{
    return A+B;
}
```

When I use DllImport in C#:

```
[DllImport("WinCE2.dll", EntryPoint = "Add")]
static extern int Add(int A, int B);
```

I always got a ***System.MissingMethodException in WinCE 5.0 emulator and WinCE6.0 Device***.

I searched some information on google, found some solution.
First, Add .def in project:

```
LIBRARY     "WinCE2"
EXPORTS
Add         DATA
```

But in a forum someone say __declspec(dllexport) can replace the .def file.
But this solution also got System.MissingMethodException.

Then I found a solution on Stack Overflow:
May I need add __cdecl key word.
And I created a Win32 DLL Project, I found the project setting will add __cdecl in default.
But Win32 Smartphone project is not.
So I try it, but also got System.MissingMethodException.
Then I try the same code in Win32 DLL and call by C#, it can work.
So I don't why wince can't work.
I had copied the dll to wince executable file folder
Can anyone share me some expeience?

Comment: Did you check with dumpbin, that the DLL exports the function with the expexted name?

Comment: I used dumpbin to check DLL, but I can't found the function.
Do I need any project setting or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You built this using the Smartphone SDK, which is ARM-based.  The CE 5.0 emulator emulated x86, so it's not going to be callable there.  If your CE 6.0 device is likewise x86-based, it too is going to have the same problem.  Try building it using an x86 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Your WinCE2.dll is not copied to WinCE device app executable folder. Try getting the same using FileInfo. I cannot find the file. Check the project settings and add the wince2.dll and set it as a content type and provide copy if newer option.

Comment: The WinCE2.dll is copied to WinCE device app executable folder.
I copied it in my WinCE emulator and WinCE device folder but also got MissingMethodException.
If the dll did not exist in flofer, maybe I got an exception like FileIsNotExist?

Comment: And .NET smartphone project can't add reference to project, so I manual copied.